# How to rewrite a function based on the natural log of each element in R

Tags: r, function

I was wondering how to take the **natural log of each element in my function** called `Like` (see below) and **then sum** them instead of using the `prod` (which multiplies them)?

**Here is my R code:**

```
Like = function(x) sapply( lapply(x, dnorm, x = seq(1, 30), 2), prod)
curve(Like, from = 13.5, to = 17.5, col = 'red', lwd = 3)
```

**I have tried the following with no success:**

```
Like = function(x) sapply( lapply(x, log(dnorm), x = seq(1, 30), 2), sum)
curve(Like, from = 13.5, to = 17.5, col = 'red', lwd = 3)
```

Comment: You can write `function(x) sapply(x, function(xi) ...))`

Comment: @Frank, I appreciate it if you could possibly write a more complete response and I could accept & upvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work (I cant see the expected output) because `dnorm` happens to have a log parameter.

```
Like = function(x)
  sapply(lapply(x, dnorm, log = TRUE, x = seq(1, 30), 2), sum)
curve(
  Like,
  from = 13.5,
  to = 17.5,
  col = 'red',
  lwd = 3
)
```

I think, the issue with your  code, is that the second parameter to `lapply` must be a function, and log(dnorm) isn't a function.

```
Like = function(x)
  sapply(lapply(x, function(z) {log(dnorm(z, x = seq(1, 30), 2))}), sum)
curve(
  Like,
  from = 13.5,
  to = 17.5,
  col = 'red',
  lwd = 3
)
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. So do we have a log-likelihood function now?

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are looking for.

```
Like = function(x) sapply( lapply(lapply(x, dnorm, x = seq(1, 30), 2),log), sum)
```

Comment: This is the more general way.